# Java Arrays: Making numbers into separated, arranged digits, output issue

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, output

I am trying to create a code in which will take a number such as this:

```
"787191230"
```

And return this:

```
"0 1 1 2 3 7 7 8 9"
```

Right now, my error is that my code is somehow printing out the first one correctly, then starts adding LOTS of 0's, in a pattern, I think. The amount of 0's increased each time seems to keep going down, but it's annoying, nevertheless.

My main code (where everything is done):

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumberSorter
{
    static int count = 0;
    private static int getNumDigits(int number)
    {
        while(number>0){

                number=number/10;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int[] getSortedDigitArray(int number)
    {
        int[] sorted = new int[getNumDigits(number)];
        for(int a = 0; a<sorted.length; a++)
        {
            sorted[a] = number%10;
            number = number/10;
        }
        for(int a = 0; a<sorted.length; a++)
        {
            int y = a;
            for(int b = a+1; b<sorted.length; b++)
            {
                if(sorted[b]<sorted[y])
                {

                    y = b;
                }
            }
            if(y != a)
            {
                int temp = sorted[y];
                sorted[y]=sorted[a];
                sorted[a]=temp;
            }
        }
        return sorted;
    }
}
```

The test case code (where all the numbers I try to decode are):

```
public class NumberSorterRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] cases = {567891, 901912468, 864213507, 898777, 234422, 29826};
        for( int test : cases )
        {
            int[] one = NumberSorter.getSortedDigitArray( test );
            for(int item : one)
            {
                System.out.print(item + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And last, but not least: The output:

```
1 5 6 7 8 9 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 4 6 8 9 9 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 7 7 8 8 9 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 3 4 4 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 6 8 9
```

Any help, hints mainly, would make me very grateful! I can't figure out what's wrong with this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yopu've declared `count` as a static, but you never reset it, so for each new test, `count` starts at the last value from the previous one.

It doesn't need to be static or widely accessible, so just move it inside the `getNumDigits()` function

Try this:

```
private static int getNumDigits(int number)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(number>0){

            number=number/10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have count as a static member of NumberSorter, you should probably keep it as a method-scoped variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getNumDigits` does not behave correctly.

```
static int count = 0;
private static int getNumDigits(int number)
{
    while(number>0){
        number=number/10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Why do you keep `count` around? Just declare a local variable:

```
private static int getNumDigits(int number)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(number>0){
        number=number/10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how a static count makes java spam 0's at me, but it did fix my issue! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try following simple code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] cases = {567891, 901912468, 864213507, 898777, 234422, 29826};
    for( int test : cases )
    {
       String numStr=String.valueOf(test);
       char[] digits=numStr.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(digits);
       String sorted=new String(digits);

        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(" "+sorted.charAt(i));                
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
1 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 1 2 4 6 8 9 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
7 7 7 8 8 9
2 2 2 3 4 4
2 2 6 8 9
```